# Meteor download binaries from server?

Tags: meteor

Using Meteor and Iron Router, is there a Meteor module that makes it easy to serve up binary files for download on the local filesystem, outside of the Meteor app container?

So if the Meteor app is in `/home/meteor/app` is it possible to provide download links to `/data/files` within Meteor?

I'm guessing the answer is No since it appears Meteor isolates itself within its container, but figured I'd ask.

I don't want to put the files in Meteor's `/public` because they need to be in a network folder, outside of the Meteor app itself.

Comment: I think it is possible to serve files from outside using this package : [`CollectionFS`](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS)

Comment: My understanding of CollectionFS is it uses the MongoDB to store information about each file, including the location of each file in the filesystem. Was hoping for something that doesn't use the database- just grabs info from a file I'm pointing to. But it would work.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't directly answer the question, but I did it like this.  There might be a better iron router way.

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/filename.txt', function(req, res, next) {
  //the filename in the url and the filename on disk don't have to be
  //the same but I made them the same here

  var fs = Npm.require('fs');

  var data = fs.readFileSync("/path/to/filename.txt");

  //if it's in the project's private directory,
  //or if you are working in a package and you added filename.txt with addAssets
  //you can probably just use
  //var data = Assets.getBinary("filename.txt");

  res.write(data);
  res.end();

});
```